# in Ruby, OptionParser returns boolean instead of input values

Tags: ruby, arguments, optparse

I'm trying to take the argument values using OptionParser.
Instead of values, my code is returning only boolean:

```
require 'optparse'

options ={}
opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|
opts.on('-v')    { |version| options[:version] = version }
opts.on('-g')    { |branch| options[:branch] = branch }
opts.on('-f')    { |full| options[:full] = full }
opts.on('-h')    { RDoc::usage }
end.parse!

# mandatory options
if (options[:version] == nil)  or (options[:branch] == nil) or (options[:full]== nil) then
    puts options[:branch]
    puts options[:version]
    puts options[:full]
    RDoc::usage('usage')
end

puts options[:branch]
```

---> TRUE

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to capture a value you need to ask for it:

```
opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|
opts.on('-v=s') { |version| options[:version] = version }
opts.on('-g=s') { |branch| options[:branch] = branch }
opts.on('-f=s') { |full| options[:full] = full }
opts.on('-h') { RDoc::usage }
```

The `=s` notation means there's an associated value.

When defining interfaces like this don't forget to include long-form names for clarity like `--version` or `--branch` so people don't have to remember `g` means "branch".

All of this is covered in the [fantastic documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) which I encourage you to read.

Comment: Also, of course, the term 's' should be replaced with something meaningful, e.g. 'branch' for '-g'.  Remember that the help text will be created using these option specifications.

Comment: Also, as an aside, `OpenStruct`s are great for storing these options.  No need to explicitly refer to hash keys nor to specify in advance attribute names (as would be necessary with `Struct`.

Comment: @KeithBennett A great point there. Like `--version=version` is better than `-v=s`. OpenStruct can keep things pretty clean if you like, but there's nothing entirely wrong with a regular Hash.

Comment: really fantastic document, +1 :)))))))